# How does the insertion of nodes in a tree work using the treelib library in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, logic

how are you guys? 
I'm having doubts with a python library, called [treelib](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/tree/2d874516d986a937420215f58143e51d3f0893b5). I noticed that when using the 'tree.show ()' function it returns the tree with the children sorted in alphabetical order and this raised the question of how the insertion in this library works. I went to their source code, but as I'm starting in python I didn't understand how the insertion of the node in the tree worked ... So, someone who uses this library knows how to inform me if in an insert like the one below:

```
tree.create ("E", 1)
tree.create ("A", 2, parent = 1)
tree.create ("B", 3, parent = 1)
```

**Who will be the son to the left of E? and who will be the son on the right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), your tree should look like this:

```
E
├── A
└── B
```

Comment: Oops, thanks for the reply. But even if I put the 'B' first and then the 'A' it will still print on the screen in the order you showed it, so who stays as a child on the left? this I cannot understand, if the first node that is inserted is inserted on the left side or on the right side of its parent node.

Comment: I think you are confusing things here, this is not a binary tree. The childs of ```E``` are being sorted, there is no right or left side.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I did'nt really realize it.